# Magento 1.9.3.4 Mails not sending

Tags: php-5.4, magento-1.9.3.3

I`ve my store on 1.9.3.4 and now my customers are not receiving order confirmation email, Contact us mail, new registration mail, forget password mail.

I tried sending through the admin panel but nothing happens, also no update email is being received. Any one can help me with this problem for magento 1.9.3.4?

My site is on Go Daddy server.
I have checked using script "mail.php" using this Mails are going.
Even I have checked var folder therew is no "log" folder.

Comment: check your logs, maybe something helpful there

Comment: I am wondering, In magento 1.9.3.4 var/log folder is missing.

Comment: for generating log you have to enable log from admin , from System-> Configuration-> Advanced-> Developer-> Log setting

Comment: check if cron is configured on your server and is running

Comment: How to check cron is enable ?

Comment: @votiveWP you can download aoe scheduler extension here  https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler and you can check cron is working or not here : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: @votiveWP Run this command in your shell ```crontab -l``` in the server  and see if there are any cron tabs listed like ```cron.sh``` or ```cron.php```. If it's not there that's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either your php mail is not serving requests or You are missing some network protocols to allow port25 open to world.

Answer (score 0):

You have to properly configure your settings to work with GoDaddy's email service.  Assuming that you have not at all changed any of the DNS settings for the mail service, and are using GoDaddy's default mail settings, then you are likely not able to send mail for a couple reasons, of which I would certainly consider any of the following:

- GoDaddy has some security measures in place with respect to insecure, non-patched Zend Framework Mail functionality.
- GoDaddy has purposefully not allowed default mailing functionality due to some sort of compliance with anti-spam policies
- You've already been black-listed mailing from the IP, which could be on a shared server.

Try getting GoDaddy's mail settings for configuring an external mail program (such as outlook) using smtp, then apply those settings to Magento's configuration for sending email using SMTP.  If needed, download an extension that will help with SMTP email.

Use tools such as mxtoolbox (search google for mxtoolbox) to help determine issues such as blacklisted, or improper DNS settings.

Consider that PHP 5.4 has been at EOL for a couple years and perhaps GoDaddy has responded with removal of known issues affecting security.

---

**Final Answer**

You have to use godaddy's servers, even if sending from gmail SMTP.

For example, sending from GMail smtp, you'll need to configure the SMTP host to relay-hosting.secureserver.net:

- "Send all emails via SMTP"
- "Set the return-path to match the From E-mail"
- "SMTP Host: relay-hosting.secureserver.net"
- "SMTP Port: 25"
- "No Encryption"
- "No SMTP Authentication"

PHP Mailing example using above:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
$mail->Username = "your-account@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "yourpassword";
```